# Connection closed with request stream and asynchronous processing

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I have a problem dealing with streams coming from an HTTP request. The handler collects the data from the stream and do some asynchronous stuff before sending the response.

As soon as stream data have been collected, the HTTP connection is closed just before `someAsyncStuff` is invoked.

This is an example that reproduce the issue. What am I doing wrong?

```js
import * as Busboy from 'busboy'
import * as express from 'express'
import { pipeline } from 'stream'
import concat = require('concat-stream')

const app = express()

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })

  busboy.on('file', (_, file) => {
    pipeline(
      file,
      concat(buffer =>
        someAsyncStuff(buffer.toString())
          .then(length => res.send({ length }))
          .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err.message))
      ),
      err => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err.message)
      }
    )
  })

  pipeline(req, busboy, err => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err.message)
  })
})

function someAsyncStuff(s: string): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(s.length), 1))
}

app.listen('3000')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using req.pipe seems to work.

```
import Busboy from 'busboy'
import express from 'express'
import { pipeline } from 'stream'
import concat from 'concat-stream'

const app = express()

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })

  busboy.on('file', (_, file) => {
    pipeline(
      file,
      concat(buffer =>
        someAsyncStuff(buffer.toString())
          .then(length => res.json({ length }))
          .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err.message))
      ),
      err => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err.message)
      }
    )
  })
  req.pipe(busboy);
})

function someAsyncStuff(s) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(s.length), 1000))
}

app.listen('3000')
```

Comment: It actually works, thanks! I didn't try it on the code where I actually have the problem yet. I would also like to understand why this is happening. It's my understanding that using `pipeline` is a best practice for piping streams (for error handling and some clean-up). Are you able to enlighten me?